# Generate DLL from C# Project using windows command line

Tags: c#, dll

I have a C# project with structure of src/test/API and src/test/Client. I have bunch of .cs files under those folders. I want to generate a single DLL from this project. How would i accomplish this? I want to use windows command prompt for this if possible. Below is the screenshot of the folder structure

[image]

Comment: can your provide a screen shot for your folders tree ..

Comment: @HanyHabib Yes, i just attached it above

Comment: why not simply `dotnet build` - or are you using .NET Framework

Comment: for .NET Framework just run `msbuild` from the project's folder

Comment: @ironstone13 I am using .NET Framework

Comment: if all of them in one proj you can use : MSBuild.exe MyProject.proj -t:rebuild

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends whether you're targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core:

- If you're targeting .NET core then navigating to the root directory of your folder and doing a `dotnet build` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) for more info) should generate a DLL for your project in the `bin` sub-directory of your project.
- If your project targets .NET Framework then you'd need to run [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019) from the root directory.

Comment: And if it's not in your path, you can run it at `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`